Submit button not inputting values properly
I have a form in cshtml that is inputting into a model but it keeps skipping some value that has been added inside the for code block, specifically the GroupPerDay values
<form method="post" asp-action="Create" class="row g-3">
    <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
        <div class="row-cols-auto">
            <input type="text" hidden class="form-control-plaintext" value="@Model.Department.DepartmentId" asp-for="Department.DepartmentId" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <label for="SubDate" class="col-form-label">NGÀY ĐĂNG KÝ: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <input type="date" id="SubDate" asp-for="DayGroup.SubcriptionDate" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DayGroup.SubcriptionDate" class="text-dark"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" value="DS HỌ TÊN" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center" value="CA 1" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center" value="CA 2" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center" value="CA 3" />
        </div>
    </div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Department.Persons.Count; i++)
    {
        int j = Model.Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay.Count - 1;
        <div class="col-auto">
            <input type="text" hidden readonly asp-for="Department.Persons[i].PersonId" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].PersonId" />
            <input type="text" hidden readonly asp-for="Department.Persons[i].Name" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].Name" />
            <input type="text" hidden readonly asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Id" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Id" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Person.Name" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Person.Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Set1" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Set2" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Set3" />
            </div>
        </div>          
    }
    <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <a class="btn btn-danger" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

The models
public class CreateGroupViewModel
{
    public string AppUserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public DayGroup DayGroup { get; set; }
}

public class DayGroup
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubcriptionDate { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public List<PersonInGroupPerDay> PersonInGroups { get; set; }
}

public class PersonInGroupPerDay
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DayGroup DayGroup { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Set1 { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Set2 { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Set3 { get; set; }
}

Input for form

The Post action model after input

I want it to add the value I input into the List
I tried <input class="btn btn-primary" type="Submit" />
and even javascript with Onclick to a function but it doesn't work
If you need more info, I can add what is needed to a comment.

Passing collections of data gets messy as hell. For a start use the debugger tools in your browser to actually capture the form POST and inspect the form data.  MVC will attempt to compose your view model class from whatever details come in from the form data fields, which are extracted from recognized elements in the page. This often means before it can re-hydrate collection children there have to be enough recognized properties for each child. (i.e. hidden inputs for values not displayed) I don't recommend mixing entities with viewmodels either.

The payload for the POST method is all populated with the correct values in the correct indexes so there is no problems with mvc composing the view model and not having values.

How do you define your model? I want it to add the value I input into the List Do you want to add the 9 numbers in the three columns CA1, CA2, and CA3?

The amount of inputs will depends on the numbers of people int he departments. The three columns are for the 3 different sets in a day, think of it like breakfast, lunch, dinner. I want the value to be associated with individual Person in the Department.

You are just adding inputs fields for the last Persons[i].GroupPerDay item.

int j = Model.Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay.Count - 1;

We also need to add hidden inputs for the remaining Persons[i].GroupPerDay items.
Try this code:
<form method="post" asp-action="Create" class="row g-3">
<div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
    <div class="row-cols-auto">
        <input type="text" hidden class="form-control-plaintext" value="@Model.Department.DepartmentId" asp-for="Department.DepartmentId" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <label for="SubDate" class="col-form-label">NGÀY ĐĂNG KÝ: </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <input type="date" id="SubDate" asp-for="DayGroup.SubcriptionDate" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="DayGroup.SubcriptionDate" class="text-dark"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mb-3 row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" value="DS HỌ TÊN" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center" value="CA 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center" value="CA 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center" value="CA 3" />
    </div>
</div>
@{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Person person in Model.Department.Persons)
    {
        int j = 0;
        foreach (var group in person.GroupPerDay)
        {
            <div class="col-auto">
                <input type="text" hidden readonly asp-for="Department.Persons[i].PersonId" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].PersonId" />
                <input type="text" hidden readonly asp-for="Department.Persons[i].Name" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].Name" />
                <input type="text" hidden readonly asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Id" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Id" />
            </div>
            if (j == person.GroupPerDay.Count - 1)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Person.Name" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Person.Name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Set1" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Set2" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Set3" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Set1" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Set2" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Set3" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Person.Name" />
                </div>
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
<div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <a class="btn btn-danger" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>

If you only want the last Persons[i].GroupPerDay item to fetch in your post action, then you should try this.
<form method="post" asp-action="Create" class="row g-3">
<div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
    <div class="row-cols-auto">
        <input type="text" hidden class="form-control-plaintext" value="@Model.Department.DepartmentId" asp-for="Department.DepartmentId" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <label for="SubDate" class="col-form-label">NGÀY ĐĂNG KÝ: </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <input type="date" id="SubDate" asp-for="DayGroup.SubcriptionDate" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="DayGroup.SubcriptionDate" class="text-dark"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mb-3 row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" value="DS HỌ TÊN" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center" value="CA 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center" value="CA 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-center" value="CA 3" />
    </div>
</div>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Department.Persons.Count; i++)
{
    int j = Model.Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay.Count - 1;
    int firstIndex = 0;
    <div class="col-auto">
        <input type="text" hidden readonly asp-for="Department.Persons[i].PersonId" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].PersonId" />
        <input type="text" hidden readonly asp-for="Department.Persons[i].Name" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].Name" />
        <input type="text" hidden readonly asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[firstIndex].Id" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Id" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[firstIndex].Person.Name" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Person.Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[firstIndex].Set1" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Set1" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[firstIndex].Set2" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Set2" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[firstIndex].Set3" value="@Model.Department.Persons[i].GroupPerDay[j].Set3" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <a class="btn btn-danger" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>

